# Select value where the value in the same row but another column is the same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to write this query, please see the columns/data:

```
ID  Type    Regnr   Samenr
1   Car      11     1
2   Plane    654    1
3   Bycicle  1311   1
4   Plane    232    2
5   Car      18     2
6   Bycicle  16     2
7   Motorcycle 13   2
```

For the [ID] number I receive I want to select the [Regnr] where the values are the same in column [Samenr] and WHERE [Type] = 'Plane'.
So if WHERE [ID] = 2, result will be 654. Or if WHERE [ID] = 1, I again get 654 as result. If WHERE [ID] = 7, the result should be 232.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use self-join

```
SELECT t2.regnr
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.samenr = t2.samenr
   AND t2.type = 'Plane'
 WHERE t1.id = ?
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/741b6/3)** demo

Comment: @GordonLinoff It has a waiting period :).